# Retrieving object from Parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6, pfobject

I'm having some struggles with the code when trying to retrieve an PFObject from Parse.

This is my code:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "message")
    query.whereKey("recipientUsername", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    var messages = query.findObjects()

    var done = false

    for message in messages {

        if done == false {

            var messageObject:PFObject =


        done == true
```

The problem is in the "var messageObject:PFObject = ". I do not know what to write to complete this statement.

Any ideas on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't `message` already a `PFObject`?

Comment: Yes it is; I'm not quite sure what that implies though. I'm just starting out in xcode and with app development.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with it.. I also don't understand what's `done` used for: retrieve and process the first element only of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you have to do with the `messageObject` variable, you don't need it. The `findObjects` method returns an array of `PFObjects`. Since I presume that under the hood it returns `NSArray`, which is translated to `[AnyObject]` in swift, you just have to downcast to an array of `PFObject`:

```
var messages = query.findObjects() as [PFObject]
```

then in your loop the `message` variable is automatically inferred the `PFObject` type, hence you don't need to create another `messageObject` variable:

```
for message in messages { // message is of PFObject type
    if done == false {
        // Do whatever you need with message
        println(message)
    }
}
```

**Update Sep 14, 2015**: as of Swift 1.2, the new `as!` *forced conversion* operator must be used:

```
var messages = query.findObjects() as! [PFObject]
```

Thanks to `@Kiran Ruth R` for pointing that out.

Comment: is it query.findObjects() as [PFObject] or query.findObjects() as! [PFObject]